# A ball that can cover all the space

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm confused: Does there exist a ball that covers all the space $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)?$

In other words, does there exist a distance $d,$ a point $x_0$ of  $\mathbb{R}^2$  and a radius $r\in ]0, +\infty[$ such that $B(x_0, r) ​​= \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: What makes you think that such a ball should exist?

Comment: @md2perpe For example with this distance ( $d(X,Y)=1$ if $X\neq Y$ et $d(X,X)=0)$we have $B(0_{\mathbb {R²}}, 2)=\mathbb R²$ ?) but i'm confused

Comment: Ah, yes, for some metrics (e.g. your example and the one presented by ECL) such balls exist. Why does that confuse you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're free to define the distance then yes, you can have a bounded distance on $\mathbb{R}^2$. For instance define
$$d(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}\,.$$
It's a distance and it's bounded by $1$. So any ball with radius $r\geq1$ is the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$.